# Get product based shipping methods in magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

Our shop has different shipping methods based in the selected products.
On the product view, I want to display additional information, based on the available shipping methods, for the given product.

Currently, I tried to use `Address::requestShippingRates` and `collectShippingRates`, but this methods require a valid quote and it feels a bit exessive to create a new quote just to list the available shipping methods.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I came up with this solution, building my own rate request with only the necessary information.

```
$quoteItem = $this->_quoteItemFactory->create();
$quoteItem->setQuote($quote);
$quoteItem->setProduct($product);

/** @var $request \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest */
$request = $this->_rateRequestFactory->create();

$request->setAllItems([$quoteItem]);
$request->setDestCountryId($this->getCurrentCountry());
$request->setStoreId($quote->getStoreId());
$request->setWebsiteId($this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getId());
$request->setBaseCurrency($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrency());
$request->setPackageCurrency($request->getBaseCurrency());

/** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
$result = $this->_rateCollector->create()->collectRates($request)->getResult();
$rates = $result->getAllRates();
```

If someone has a better approach, feel free to correct me - I'm open for suggestions

Comment: Are you sure this is the right class : `\Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result` ?

Comment: Because while implementing the same, I'm getting an error that `collectRates` not found in the specified class.